# In case of OS and MBR malware, what will be the difference between a factory reset, a format and a disk wipe?

Tags: windows-10, formatting, mbr, malware-removal, wipe

In case of malware infection in latest windows OS, like win 10, which is the best course of action for complete disinfection - a factory reset using troubleshoot and recovery, a format of entire drive done with Windows built-in disk management tool, or a disk wipe done with third party data erasure softwares?

What are the differences between these three? If the infection has spread to the master boot record, which of these three, if any, should be able to fix that as well alongside OS infection?

Also, if I understand correctly, disk wipe and low level format are the one and the same for modern machines?

(Not taking any firmware or hardware malware into account, just OS and MBR infections.)

EDIT: I do not want to know how to run antivirus tools to remove the malware, or IF I should format, as the answers to other similar looking questions have stated. I want to know the differences between the three different processes of starting over and reinstalling Windows, and which one is the best bet for malware. I have seen the words formatting and wiping being thrown around somewhat interchangeably on the threads and forums, and I feel that the two processes are actually a little different, but I'm not sure. Can malware which isn't firmware/hardware and is limited to OS/MBR actually survive a format, such that I would need to use third party tools to perform complete disk erasure? Because from what I understand, after formatting, the data is pretty much gone until you run special recovery tools on it and even then it might be uncertain. What are the odds of OS infections persisting after format and not wipe? I am looking for an explanation on the difference a full drive format with disk management tool, and a disk wipe with third party tool can have on various types of malware, whether those differences are theoretical or low odds.

Comment: I have edited the question and highlighted how my question is different from the one it has been marked as duplicate of. I actually read that thread before posting this and the answers on it do not answer my concerns. I request you to kindly reopen my question. Thank you.

Comment: Your question regarding the differences has been answered before, but not so much in this context.  I'll vote to reopen because there could be some general value to an answer specifically in the context of malware (including why).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. The differences were explained in case of erasing regular data, not about malware and how it can persist and what are the odds of that. Thank you for reviewing @fixer1234

Comment: Your question could be improved by completely removing any hint of asking how to remove malware. Instead, simply ask if malware can survive each of the three ways to "start over" and what differences between those reset actions lead to malware being able to survive them.